# Checkout a working copy of a SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, svn

I think the title speaks for itself. I need to checkout a working copy of a database on SQL Server, to my own computer, using C#. Pretty much like SVN. In this copy I must be able to update/insert/delete like using the original database, and then, in the end, commit the changes to the server. Pretty much like SVN i guess.

Comment: Lol... this is pretty much not the type of things you ask on here...

Comment: http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

Comment: I'm not asking for solutions, I'm asking for "directions". I'm pretty lost with this project, and not particularly familiar with either C# or SQL Server. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be fair - version-controlling an entire database is outlandishly complicated. Especially if you're unfamiliar with the technology you're using. You'll have to consider existing connections, size, the fact that it's binary so you can't diff it, so on and so forth.

Comment: I'd probably be able to compare only the differences between both databases, but that's only after all the changes have been made, and since they can be made pretty much everywhere on the database, I must have access to everything locally. But thank you for your suggestion

Comment: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not check out databases. You develop scripts and keep under source control scripts that modify the database. Then you apply your scripts to whatever database you want, to bring it to the desired state. This applies to reference data as well. Read how [Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) work to better understand the concept.

Things that help doing this: [Visual studio Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx), [RedGate SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/). You can also simply [roll your own solution](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/) once you understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm note quite sure what you want but consider :

- Checking about the entity framework
- Backup the current databse, import in your PC, do your changes, do a backup of your modified database and use restore to update the server database.